# Why is temp array changing my state array? Sharepoint 2019 on premise, React, Typescript

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, 2019, react, typescript

I do not know why function `setHours()` that should work only on `tempEvent` is also changing my state `this.state.events` (it sets hours of my dates to `00:00:00`.

```
  let tempEvent = this.state.events[i]["start"];
  tempEvent.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  if (tempEvent.getDate() == date.getDate()) {
    allEventsInADayIndex.push(i);
  }
```

I also tried to copy the events state into another array and then set it as a new state but that didn't seem to work either.

```
let realEvenets = [];
for (let i = 0; i < this.state.events.length; i++) {
  let tempEvent = this.state.events[i]["start"];
  realEvenets.push(this.state.events[i]);
  tempEvent.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  if (tempEvent.getDate() == date.getDate()) {
    allEventsInADayIndex.push(i);
  }
}
this.setState({ events: realEvenets });
```

The question is how can I use `setHours` to `tempEvent` array and keep the state untouched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because it is creating shallow copy of state. I will suggest you to use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library to make the deep copy of your state easily.

Add import statement in your code file like:

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
```

You can use:

```
let localState = _.cloneDeep(this.state);
let tempEvents = localState.events[i]["start"];
```

**Note**: If lodash library is not installed already then you can install it using `npm i lodash`.